# Instalar keyring en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, encriptación, codificación

Estoy tratando de instalar y configurar el plugin keyring para poder encriptar una base de datos existente en MySQL.

Mi versión de `MySQL` es `5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

En el archivo de configuración `/etc/mysql/my.conf` he puesto el siguiente código

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
keyring_file_data=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring
```

Tras hacer esto, he generado el directorio con los siguientes comandos.

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
mkdir mysql-keyring
chmod 750 mysql-keyring
chown mysql mysql-keyring
chgrp mysql mysql-keyring
```

Una vez finalizados estos dos puntos, he reiniciado el servicio de mysql con el comando

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Paso a testear si el plugin esta correctamente activado, lanzo la consulta

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
       WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

La respuesta es la siguiente

```
+--------------+---------------+
| PLUGIN_NAME  | PLUGIN_STATUS |
+--------------+---------------+
| keyring_file | ACTIVE        |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Por lo tanto, el plugin debe estar correctamente activado.

Llega el momento de comenzar con las pruebas, el objetivo final es poder encriptar una base de datos completa (la cuál ya esta creada y tiene datos), para evitar esa posible fuga de información si se exporta fuera nuestro servidor.

Comienzo por crear una tabla de cero, para ver si funciona todo correctamente.

Al lanzar el comando

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 INT) ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

Me devuelve el error

```
/* Error de SQL (3185): Can't find master key from keyring, please check keyring plugin is loaded. */
```

Y cualquier consulta que intento lanzar de creación de tablas me devuelve lo mismo.

Si lanzo el comando, para actualizar una tabla InnoDB me devuelve el mismo error.

```
ALTER TABLE DetallesFacturasVarios ENCRYPTION='Y';

/* Error de SQL (3185): Can't find master key from keyring, please check keyring plugin is loaded. */
```

He investigado y no he dado con la solución para crear esta key. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: después de 8 meses supongo que ya lo tendrás solucionado.
Lo anterior me ayuda mucho. Pero, ¿has creado las keys? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/keyring-service.html Si alguien lo entiende bien y sabe como hacerlo, estaría fenomenal que lo pusiese por aquí Saludos.

Comment: No uses la zonavde respursyas para hacer preguntas al OP lee [ask] , borra esto y abre una nueva pregunta

Comment: @FernandoJiménez La verdad que no, parece ser que solo funciona con el de pago (enterprise) Conseguí codificar una vista, pero no era lo que buscaba. Lo dicho, haz una nueva pregunta y la gente te intentará ayudar (quizás hasta a mi me venga bien) ;)